# i have a problem with the input.getaxisraw method in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i was trying to make it so you can move the camera by dragging with the mouse

```
void Update(){
if (mouseDown)
        {
            float xInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
            float yInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
            cam.Translate(xInput * movingSpeed, yInput * movingSpeed, 0);
        }
}
```

and i got this error:  GetAxisRaw is not allowed to be called from a MonoBehaviour constructor (or instance field initializer), call it in Awake or Start instead

this is strange because i have used this method in update many times and never encountered that error

i tried to move the declaration of the variables to outside of the update method and only set them to the getaxisraw inside of the update but it did not work

Comment: it would suggest you need to reformat your code, and that this is not where you think it is

Comment: BugFinder said it a bit cryptic, but your code is very likely in a scope that it shouldn't be in. If you have trouble identifying where to move it post the full script.

Comment: i think it was just a unity bug because the problem disappeared the moment i restarted the unity editor